# ambiguous call to method with enable_if with sizeof... condition

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

```
template<typename... Tn>
std::enable_if<sizeof...(Tn) == 0, void>
insert(T&& value) {
}
template<typename... Tn>
std::enable_if<sizeof...(Tn) != 0, void>
insert(T&& value) {
}
```

As per compilation error a call to e.g. `obj.insert<double>(value)` is ambiguous. But why is it ambiguous, when `sizeof...` can only be either 0 or not 0?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ http://ideone.com/2PvkWk - But what information is missing in the question that you need that?

Comment: It would be great when the persons who vote a question down would take a few seconds to add a comment explaining why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration was malformed. The correct syntax would be:

```
template<typename... Tn>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Tn) == 0, void>::type
insert(T&& value) {
}
```

Note the added `typename` and `::type`.